# Проблема со светом в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичок в работе со светом в Unity, посмотрел много туториалов и решил использовать URP. Вроде всё настроил, но когда я ставлю освещение, то на текстуры у меня не ложиться свет, а наоборот красит их как будто. Может я чего-то не понимаю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]